# R shiny publish issue Unhandled Exception: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: r, shiny

I was trying to publish my shiny app, it works fine in local, but when I try to publish it, i got this error:
Unhandled Exception: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error

What does this mean?
Don't know which part goes wrong, hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, looks like they are having server issues...

**HTTP 500 refers to an issue with the web server (service)**, don't worry it's not a problem on your end.

**See: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html**

You can periodically try to publish again until it works. You can also check the Shiny Google Discussion Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shiny-discuss for shinyapps.io